# Why doesn't my eclipse show me the java project?

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse software, for some reasons it doesn't show me the table where to put folders, yes I dud set up a Java project (image below)

[image]

Comment: [Window > Show View > Project Explorer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-find-package-explorer-in-Java-eclipse-project) (link is to an image and the first result on google when searching ‘eclipse show project’.)

Comment: I guess to answer the question though: the project explorer got closed somehow (accidental click, prankster classmate, background radiation flipping bits on your computer, who knows).

Comment: @BeUndead already answer the suitable approach

Answer (score 1):

The project explorer sometimes disappears if you double tap on the bar at the top with all your tabs. If you **double tap on the bar with your tabs** again, it should open.

If this doesn't work go to **Window > Show View > Project Explorer.**
This will open up the Project Explorer with your files, and if you are missing a Console, etc. you can use this method as well. If all else fails, **Window** > **Perspective** > **Reset Perspective**.

Hope that helped!